# Why is solution of NDSolve different than Heun's method?

Tags: differential-equations

I am thrying to solve the Lorrentz system using both the Heun's numerical method given by the following code

```
Clear["Global`*"]
S[a_, b_, c_, h_, N_] := (x[0] = a; y[0] = b; z[0] = c; 
  Do[{x[n + 1] = 
     x[n] + h*
       f[x[n] + h/2*f[x[n], y[n], z[n]], 
        y[n] + h/2*g[x[n], y[n], z[n]], 
        z[n] + h/2*p[x[n], y[n], z[n]]], 
    y[n + 1] = 
     y[n] + h*
       g[x[n] + h/2*f[x[n], y[n], z[n]], 
        y[n] + h/2*g[x[n], y[n], z[n]], 
        z[n] + h/2*p[x[n], y[n], z[n]]], 
    z[n + 1] = 
     z[n] + h*
       p[x[n] + h/2*f[x[n], y[n], z[n]], 
        y[n] + h/2*g[x[n], y[n], z[n]], 
        z[n] + h/2*p[x[n], y[n], z[n]]]}, {n, 0, N}])

f[x_, y_, z_] = s*(y - x);
g[x_, y_, z_] = x*(r - z) - y;
p[x_, y_, z_] = x*y - b*z;
s = 5;
r = 28;
b = 8/3;

S[0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.05, 100/0.05]
X = Interpolation[Table[{n, x[n]}, {n, 0, 100/0.05}]]
Y = Interpolation[Table[{n, y[n]}, {n, 0, 100/0.05}]]
Z = Interpolation[Table[{n, z[n]}, {n, 0, 100/0.05}]]


fig1 = ParametricPlot3D[{X[n], Y[n], Z[n]}, {n, 0, 500}]
```

and Mathematica's NDSolve

```
Clear["Global`*"]
f[a_, b_, c_] := 
 NDSolve[{x[0] == a, y[0] == b, z[0] == c, x'[t] == 5*(y[t] - x[t]), 
   y'[t] == x[t]*(28 - z[t]) - y[t], 
   z'[t] == x[t]*y[t] - 8/3*z[t]}, {x[t], y[t], z[t]}, {t, 0, 100}]
s1 = f[0.001, 0.001, 0.001]
ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t], z[t]} /. s1], {t, 0, 50}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
s2 = f[0.00101, 0.00101, 0.00101]

Plot[{x[t] /. s1, x[t] /. s2}, {t, 0, 50}]
Plot[{y[t] /. s1, y[t] /. s2}, {t, 0, 50}]
Plot[{z[t] /. s1, z[t] /. s2}, {t, 0, 50}]
```

However the solutions are a lot different for those two methods.
Why is this happening? Is there a problem why my code or with the parameters (like time step) of Heun's method?

Comment: You could check your Heun's method code against Heun's method in `NDSolve`: `HeunCoefficients[2, p_] := N[{{{1}}, {1/2, 1/2}, {1}}, p];
Block[{h = 0.05},
sol = NDSolve[  ..., 
   Method -> {"FixedStep", Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", "Coefficients" -> HeunCoefficients, "DifferenceOrder" -> 2}}, 
   StartingStepSize -> h]
 ]`

Comment: Try e.g. `h=0.04` for Heun's method.

Answer (score 6):

There is typos in the code with `N` using as a limit in `Do` loop and with `X,Y,Z` definitions. Also we need to localize variables in `NDSolve` with using `Module`. The code for comparison two methods can be written as follows

```
Clear["Global`*"]
f[x_, y_, z_] := s*(y - x);
g[x_, y_, z_] := x*(r - z) - y;
p[x_, y_, z_] := x*y - b*z;
S[x0_, y0_, z0_, h_, nn_] := (x[0] = x0; y[0] = y0; z[0] = z0;
  Do[{x[n + 1] = 
     x[n] + h*
       f[x[n] + h/2*f[x[n], y[n], z[n]], 
        y[n] + h/2*g[x[n], y[n], z[n]], 
        z[n] + h/2*p[x[n], y[n], z[n]]], 
    y[n + 1] = 
     y[n] + h*
       g[x[n] + h/2*f[x[n], y[n], z[n]], 
        y[n] + h/2*g[x[n], y[n], z[n]], 
        z[n] + h/2*p[x[n], y[n], z[n]]], 
    z[n + 1] = 
     z[n] + h*
       p[x[n] + h/2*f[x[n], y[n], z[n]], 
        y[n] + h/2*g[x[n], y[n], z[n]], 
        z[n] + h/2*p[x[n], y[n], z[n]]]}, {n, 0, nn}])





    HeunCoefficients[2, par_] := 
 N[{{{1}}, {1/2, 1/2}, {1}}, par]; op = {"ExplicitRungeKutta", 
  "Coefficients" -> HeunCoefficients, "DifferenceOrder" -> 2}; 
S1[x0_, y0_, z0_, tmax_] := 
 Module[{tm = tmax, x, y, z}, 
  sol = NDSolveValue[{x[0] == x0, y[0] == y0, z[0] == z0, 
     x'[t] == s*(y[t] - x[t]), y'[t] == x[t]*(r - z[t]) - y[t], 
     z'[t] == x[t]*y[t] - b*z[t]}, {x[t], y[t], z[t]}, {t, 0, tm}, 
    Method -> op, StartingStepSize -> h]; sol]

s = 5;
r = 28;
b = 8/3; h = 1/200; tmax = 100; nmax = Round[tmax/h];

S[0.001, 0.001, 0.001, h, nmax];
X = Interpolation[Table[{h n, x[n]}, {n  , 0, nmax}]];
Y = Interpolation[Table[{h n, y[n]}, {n, 0, nmax}]];
Z = Interpolation[Table[{h n, z[n]}, {n, 0, nmax}]];  
s1 = S1[0.001, 0.001, .001, 100];
```

Visualization

```
{ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[s1], {t, 0, tmax}, PlotRange -> All, 
  ColorFunction -> Hue, PlotLabel -> "NDSolve", 
  PlotTheme -> "Scientific"], 
 ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[{X[t], Y[t], Z[t]}], {t, 0, tmax}, 
  PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> Hue, 
  PlotLabel -> "Heun's method", PlotTheme -> "Scientific"]}
```

[image: Figure 1]
Even two solutions look identical, nevertheless there is a difference of `h` order at `t` about 1 as it shown below

```
Plot[Norm[s1 - {X[t], Y[t], Z[t]}], {t, 0, tmax}, PlotPoints -> 200, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Figure 2]